# How to perform asynchronous onSuspend of Chrome Extension Event Page?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

The documentation on [Chrome's Event Pages' `onSuspend` event](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onSuspend) states:

> **onSuspend**
>
> Sent to the event page just before it is unloaded. This gives the extension opportunity to do some clean up. Note that since the page is unloading, any asynchronous operations started while handling this event are not guaranteed to complete. If **more activity** for the event page occurs before it gets unloaded the onSuspendCanceled event will be sent and the page won't be unloaded.

I actually need to perform an asynchronous request. Is there a workaround for this, maybe utilising Promises?

If none, the documentation says `onSuspendCanceled` is sent if "more activity" occurs: What exactly are these activities and how may I create them so I can trigger onSuspendCanceled and prevent unloading?

Comment: When you want to prevent unloading, simply do something every 1 second using setInterval or setTimeout e.g. `fetch(location.href)` in the event page.

Comment: I've found that sometimes just doing a fetch is not enough. You might want to also create an app window with a message like "cleaning up work... please wait"